# Replace the misleading [unity] tag with a more distinct tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There are several commonly known products referred to as "unity". These include:

- [Unity3d gaming engine](http://unity3d.com/) [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) [unityscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unityscript)
- [Unity Application Block (.net IoC container)](https://unity.codeplex.com/) [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity)
- [Ubuntu Unity Desktop Environment](https://unity.ubuntu.com/) [ubuntu-unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-unity)

Currently the tag [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) refers to the .NET IoC container. However, it seems that a lot of the questions regarding [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d), [unityscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unityscript) and [ubuntu-unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-unity) get falsely tagged with [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity).
It's quite a lot of "unnecessary" work to edit a few questions daily to fix the tags.

I suggest renaming the [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) tag to [unity-ioc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-ioc) or something the like [unity-di](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-di) (...) and removing the [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) tag completely (and for ever).

PS: if you go looking for "wrongly assigned tags" you won't find that many (recent ones) because i just fixed a bunch of them:

- [Unity iOS app's screen goes black on startup, but still appears to be running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456021/unity-ios-apps-screen-goes-black-on-startup-but-still-appears-to-be-running)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460908/the-unity-aspect-ratio-script-looks-good-in-computer-but-not-in-android-phones
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474508/assigning-to-a-2d-list
- [Unity 4.6 - How to scale GUI elements to the right size for every resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477492/unity-4-6-how-to-scale-gui-elements-to-the-right-size-for-every-resolution)
- [Unity consume key and motion events in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478811/unity-consume-key-and-motion-events-in-android)

Comment: Yep, this is [not just a problem on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212703/show-stack-overflow-tag-wiki-information-to-employers-on-the-careers-site) ...

Comment: MS seems to have a hard time deciding on an official name. The [documentation home](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff647202.aspx) calls it *Unity Container*, *Unity* and *Unity Application Block*. The [release notes](https://unity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Unity3ReleaseNotes) of v3 do the same thing.

Comment: I'm surprised it doesn't also get confused with the Ubuntu desktop environment of the same name. (That's the first thing I think of!)

Comment: @sevenseacat: you're right. thanks. It does happen: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21074353/revisions

Comment: Good suggestion. The MSDN summary page says "Unity is a lightweight, extensible dependency injection container...". So, "unity-di" gets my vote.

Comment: I've retagged a few left misstagged posts. Spot-checking a 100 posts did not reveal any further miss tagged posts. Could a mod now please rename [unity] to [unity-di] so this can be put to bed? Thanks.

Comment: I just tried clearing out the unity question from unity3d ones, and it seems like a loosing battle. Clearly something should be done about that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rename \[Unity\] tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287652/rename-unity-tag)

Comment: Yes please! I just reviewed the newest [unity] questions, and the first three should have been tagged [unity3d]. (Unfortunately I can only suggest edits, not actually make them ... need 700 more rep before I can retag without someone else's help.)

Comment: There is also the gamedev stack exchange site -- arguably questions about unity3d should be directed there. (Where, to confuse things further, the tag is simply "unity" -- http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity)

Comment: This concern is almost a year old now, and there is still the "confusing plain unity" tag. How to make progress here? Who can/should change it?

Comment: @d4Rk well i've been thinking about this several times so far. The only way that i know which might escalate things further is: 1st make sure that all posts are correctly tagged, 2nd immediately flag this post for moderator attention and ask him to do the tag-renaming.

Comment: @d4Rk i just went over last few months [unity] questions, re-tagged where necessary, and flagged this question for moderator attention.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit Ok that's what I do either, it's somehow also nice to get some rep of doing so, but that's definitely not the intention of stackoverflow, I guess..

Comment: The problem still exists today; retagging questions manually won't make it go away. This tag really needs to be renamed (`[unity-container]` [seems to be a good choice](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287661/98713))

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the long wait! I'm looking at the tagged questions and still see a lot of unity3d questions tagged [tag:unity], probably because the rename didn't happen (Again, sorry!) If you're willing to make a small push again and retag, I will rename the tag.

Comment: I've reviewed the questions from around June 2015 to present, and they seem to be clear of any explicit [tag:unity3d] mix-ups. Flagging this question for moderator attention again so we can hopefully put this confusion to rest at last.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha is your offer still standing?

Comment: Absolutely! Ping me about it when you're done.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Serlite says it's done ;-) see 2 comments above (thanks Serlite)

Comment: Done! The old [tag:unity] is no more. I've renamed it to [tag:unity-container] and *have not* create a synonym. I will let those with some proficiency in the tag determine whether a synonym is required or not. Please review my actions and tell me whether they're satisfactory. cc @Serlite

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Thanks! i guess there's no feature to "block" the [unity] tag from being recreated? Because i fear that someone may be re-creating it, either for unity the di container, or for unity, the game engine... however, since unity is ambiguous it shouldn't be created for either.

Comment: There is the blacklist, but I doubt it will be used here. The best way is to just create a synonym to the tag it's most appropriate to. Nevertheless, when a user types "unity" they'll be presented with options, and low rep users cannot create tags. So I think we're pretty much covered for most cases.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha can we have a synonym [unity] pointing to both [unity-container] and [unity3d]? Because they're both perfect matches. Maybe even the unity desktop environment. Otherwise i'd rather skip it, because it might lead people to assign the wrong tag, again. Typing `[unity` now suggests [unity3d] and [unity-container] etc. already. So i don't think we actually need a synonym :-)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha The `unity` tag was recreated a few days ago by a user that didn't know that `ubuntu-unity` existed. Right now the `unity` tag is being used mostly for `unity3d` questions, and even has its own tag wiki approved that is a duplicate of `unity3d`. What would you propose we do?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister remove the tag from all questions not matching `unity3d`, and I'll create a synonym.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Just did a bit of retagging. All questions tagged `unity` right now are referencing `unity3d` to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: I've retagged all remaining questions unity3d, and created a synonym from unity to unity3d. That should do it for the tag.

Answer (score 4):

After some nice retagging work, the [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) tag is no more. All questions are now tagged appropriately, and a synonym from [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) to [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) has been created.

If anyone wants to dispute the synonym or has further questions, please open a new meta post and link to this one.

Comment: I would have prefered a blacklist. unity3d guys will cry foul.

Comment: Thanks for your work. However, unity is just as much unity the container and unity the linux thingy even if unity3d occurs more often. I thought the work was done on January 21st? Why the change now? Was the [unity] tag popping up again?

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit Yes, apparently, the tag was created anew before a synonym was created for it. So I've created one for it.