# Rename [Unity] tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Given that [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) has the following in the description.

> DO NOT USE ON QUESTIONS ABOUT THE UNITY GAME ENGINE (use: [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) instead)!!

Perhaps it is badly named to begin with.

I suggest we rename the tag as one of the following to avoid this in future.

- [msunity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msunity)
- [unity-ioc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-ioc)
- [unity-di](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-di)
- [unityapplicationblock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unityapplicationblock)
- [unity.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity.net)

Comment: Maybe "unity.net"?

Comment: @Deduplicator That might work, however my worry would be that, [tag:unity3d] being heavily based on mono, might still be confused with [tag:unity.net].

Comment: Fun fact: there's also the unity shell, luckily, it seems that the qml and qt tags (and AU) absorbed those questions.

Comment: Should there be a separate `unity2d` tag? http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/2d

Comment: @bonh [tag:unity3d] is broad enough and the tag excerpt mentions 2d as well.

Answer (score 33):

I think it is a good idea to rename it. I often retag question to [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d), cause many new users think the tag [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) is about the Unity game engine what its not.

The [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) has also more questions (about 8000) than the [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) (about 2000) and I think most people think that when they see the Unity tag that a question is about the game engine and not the IOC-Container.

So to help new users and to avoid such retagging I recommend to rename the tag [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) to [unitycontainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unitycontainer) or [unity-container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-container), cause Microsoft do name the IOC-Container that way on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647202.aspx). And after that to use the tag [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) for the Unity Game Engine.

As a Unity Container interested person, I could live with the reuse of the [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) for the Unity Game Engine.

Comment: Maybe better also a synonym from unity to unity3d, to make it obvious when anything but unity3d was meant? (At least for those giving it a second glance at all...)

Comment: [tag:unity-container] seems the best choice to me.

Comment: @dav_i Yes for ne too

Comment: Just noting that the makers of the game engine now consistently refer to their own tool as Unity not Unity 3D, likely because they have made a big push to add 2D features/tools in recent years. This fact is another reason for using the unity tag for the game engine.

Comment: microsoft is also consistenly referencing to unity as unity.. so i think the best thing would be to get rid of  [unity] and "lock" it so it cannot be recreated. Then use something specific for [unity-container] and [unity-game-engine] or something like that... avoids name conflicts and it will still pop up when you type it in.

Comment: There are more questions about the Unity game engine that are mistagged with [unity] each day than actual questions about Unity container.