# Unity-ifying Unity5 in to unity3d-5

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

By the way, when I first posted this, I didn't realise there was some vast confusion about "the official product name".

The *web site URL* for "Unity Technologies" is unity3d.com.  But regarding the literal product name,

actual license ... (four year old example) ..

[image]

Actual product web site...

[image]

[image]

Actual purchase page...

[image]

---

every 'unity5' tag is about the Unity game engine.

every 'unity4' tag is about the Unity game engine.

It's very common to ask "version-related" questions in that field regarding unity5 and unity4 - not unlike [windows-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-10) and [windows-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-8).

Comment: Tag requests on meta have flashy titles, how about "Uniting unity3d-5 and unity-5"?

Comment: Another tag that also seems to bear the same meaning is the (currently much more popular) tag [tag:unity5].

Comment: shouldn't this have [tag:burninate-request]?

Comment: @JoeBlow Not exactly what I had in mind, but go ahead, it's your post.

Comment: Unity is also the shell used by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: @Braiam The Ubuntu shell is unrelated, to the tag, as stack overflow is about programming questions and most of the unity related questions are about the Unity Application Block (.NET IoC Container). On superuser this may be more related to ubuntu

Comment: @Tseng cool, because Ubuntu Unity has an API aimed to develop for both mobile and desktop devices http://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/

Comment: There is already a [tag:ubuntu-unity] tag for this type of questions, which are an absolute minority due to the low popularity of it. There are only 81 questions for ubuntu-unity compared to over 2700 for unity tag (the IoC container)

Comment: Maybe the unity tag should be changed for the more popular use.

Comment: @Marsh I strongly oppose that idea. [unity] would be ambiguous, that's never good. With [unity] = the IOC container, a lot of miss-taggings actually happened (using [unity] instead of [unity3d]). However, if [unity] were to mean the game engine, albeit fewer, there'd still be plenty of miss-taggings. This leaves reviewers with a lot of unnecessary, manual work. it would be nice if [unity] could be blocked from creation entirely. However, since i believe it's not, i guess we might be able to alleviate the issue a bit by creating tag synonyms like [unity2d] - if necessary.

Comment: @Joe-Blow [unity] has just now been renamed to [unity-container] as there's been a lot of misstaggings.

Comment: for God's sake, ***don't make "unity2d"***.  I'm not sure if you're a game engineer, but within the Unity3D product, there's actually -- of course -- "Unity 2D for Unity3D" (ie a product section you use to make 2D games, using "Unity3D")  Just google, the most common thing in the world is to mention "I'm doing it using unity 2d" meaning, "the 2d facility in the product Unity3D".

Answer (score 2):

[unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) and [unity3d-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-5) should be unified. [unity4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity4)/[unity5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5) shouldn't go into [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d).

[unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) is a dependency injection container from Microsoft Practice & Patterns team (currently version 4) and are not to be confused with [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) game engine/middleware.

Comment: So, [tag:unity4] is very ambiguous!

Comment: Based on the popularity (or lack thereof) of [tag:unity4] in Microsoft Unity questions, I'm going to hazard a guess that there will be similarly little usage of [tag:unity5] for Microsoft Unity should it ever reach version 5. This may be a non-issue...? A better approach may be to revise the oft-misused [tag:unity], as [suggested here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269701/replace-the-misleading-unity-tag-with-a-more-distinct-tag). (I'm going to see if I can do the retagging and finally get a mod to do the rename.)

Comment: suggesting that Unity3D and Unity3D-5 (and/or Unity3D-4) should be unified, is not sensible.  It would be like trying to get rid of the WIndows-10, Windows-8 (etc) tags.  It's absolutely normal and very frequent to ask Unity3D version related questions (how do you do this in Unity3D 5? what changed in Unity3D 4? type of thing).  Almost certainly, every single "unity4" and "unity5" question would be about those issues in Unity3D

Comment: I just checked and I believe every "Unity5" question is about Unity the game engine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5  Note that indeed, very often people tag both Unity3D and Unity5, since, it is very common to ask those "version-related" questions, when working on Unity

Comment: Unity3d is the official brand name of the Engine from Unity Technologies, so the tag should clearly be related to "unity3d" and not "unity". The unity tag has ever since been used for the IoC .NET container. So unity5 makes no sense to use with the engine, as it's neither the products brand name and it's similarities to the "unity" tag are too big

Comment: "Unity3d is the official brand name of the Engine from Unity Technologies" This seems absolutely incorrect, who suggested this and why?  I have never heard that.  I'll post a screen-shot of some **official invoices**