# Should we burninate the [unity5] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

I've noticed that we have a tag for [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) and [unity5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5) and they both have the same description.

Below I've listed why this tag should no longer be on the website following the guidelines listed here: [What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070/)

> 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=unity5), there are questions being posted with this tag as recently as just yesterday.

Looking at the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54807784).

I maybe be nitpicking here but the user posted:

> `GameManager.Instance.AudioSource.PlayOneShot(SoundManager.Instance.Swipe);`

`AudioSource.PlayOneShot` did not exist in Unity until 2017, two years after unity5.

The question however is tagged with [unity5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5) and [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d), leading one to assume that people are confused as to which one they should pick so they choose both, or they have a false belief they will receive more help for having more relevant tags. However I believe that having outdated tags can often be more confusing.

> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Does it make sense to have a question asked about code that does not exist anymore? Furthermore does it make sense for users to tag a question with a tag that implies they are using a version of a framework that they are not actually using? In my opinion having a [unity5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5) tag leads to more confusion then anything especially for me if I go to answer a question that has [unity5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5) tag on it. I may just skip over the question believing they are using an outdated engine when they may just be confused and are using the latest version which results in the end user not getting the help they need.

> 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Adding [unity5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5) does add meaning to the post, but the description does not describe that meaning accurately. The description for the tag is the same as for [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d), so it would make sense that users would use both tags on their question however a more accurate description would be:

> A specific version of unity that implies outdated or depreciated code

> 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

The way the tag is currently portrayed it means the same thing as [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) but it is based on a specific version of `unity5` which leads to confusion.

In reality, if we have a tag for [unity5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5), we might as well have a tag for all versions: [unity2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity2017), [unity2017.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity2017.2), [unity2017.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity2017.4), etc.

Why do we have a specific tag for [unity5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5); it just does not make any logical sense in the being that its adds no value to a question ask and does lead to confusion?

If I add the `unity5` tag to my post it should mean that I am using a specific version of the code that I need help with and does not need to be generalized with `unity3d` because they are two very different things.

Personally I think the tag should be burned but maybe a better solution would be to change the description more accurately to explain the use for the tag.

Comment: [Self-repost of a now deleted question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380466/should-we-burninate-the-unity5-tag). And unity5 is still an alias of unity3d. You can't burninate aliases...

Comment: *Does it make sense to have a question asked about code that does not exist anymore?* It does make sense if you have to maintain a project running on Unity5.

Comment: How many users that are tagging questions with the tag `unity5` are actually using unity5 though? @BDL

Comment: Related: [Unity-ifying Unity5 in to unity3d-5](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315065/7795130), [which tag should be used [unity5\] or [unity3d\]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366062/7795130), [Dissolve unity's union: [unity3d\] and [unity5\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365791/7795130)

Comment: @JosephWilliamson: "*How many users that are tagging questions with the tag unity5 are actually using unity5 though?*" Does it matter? It's an alias. It gets transformed into the main tag.

Comment: @NicolBolas but they mean 2 different things if I tag a question with unity5 it should mean that I am using a specific version of code that I need help with

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=unity5

Comment: @JosephWilliamson: "*if I tag a question with unity5 it should mean that I am using a specific version of code that I need help with*" Which is a fact you can mention *in your question*.

Comment: I will say however, thank you for following the full burnination process in your question. We get far too many people who just say "I don't like this tag, plz2burn?" and I appreciate you going through the steps so that we can focus on if it should be burned rather than how the question is presented.

Comment: I'm not sure that you understood what Zoe told, basically the [unity5] tag is a synonyms of [unity3d] see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unity3d/synonyms, this means it's remapped to unity3d. Hence it's hard to understand what you really would like to happen.

Comment: Burning the tag may not be entirely applicable but at the very least the tag should have a more clear and concise description to prevent misuse of the tag @PetterFriberg

Answer (score 5):

This tag unambiguously identifies a programming topic and can only have one meaning. Also, by your own admission, this tag *does* add information to the post. That being said, this doesn’t really meet any of the criteria.

The fact that the tag is frequently misused is not a valid reason to burninate it.

Also, it’s very common to have tags for different versions of the same technology.

Comment: You should consider in this answer that it is already a synonym see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unity3d/synonyms

Comment: Burning the tag may not be entirely applicable but at the very least the tag should have a more clear and concise description to prevent misuse of the tag @EJoshuaS

Comment: @Joseph If you think the excerpt or wiki of a tag can be improved, just suggest an edit. You don't need to raise anything on meta for that.

Comment: Where would I find that at @ErikA

Comment: @JosephWilliamson: Click on the [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) and check the first row of links directly below the brief tag description. There you can find an [Improve tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/28511) link.

Comment: A bit late, but if we'd burninate misused tags, pretty much all the major IDE tags would have to be burninated.