# Different tag synonym remapping for Unity3d tag: unity or unity-game-engine

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

Currently all tags that are synonyms for the Unity game engine are remapped to [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d), including the tags [unity-game-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-game-engine) and simply [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity).

The problem with this is a lot of people misinterpret this to be asking specifically about the 3D mode within the game engine, and people often feel the need to specify that "they are using the 2D mode but couldn't find a tag for it", when the tag is actually for the game engine itself.

I feel this causes unnecessary confusion, "Unity3d" <s>is not</s> *is no longer* a common name for the engine outside this site, and in my opinion it would be better to make the default tag either  [unity-game-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-game-engine) or [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity). That way the rest of them could be mapped onto [unity-game-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-game-engine) as synonyms.

I'm not certain how this process works, perhaps I'm misunderstanding a complexity of tag-synonyms. Is there a reason this would be difficult or impractical to achieve? Or another reason this change shouldn't be made?

I'm aware that there were some conflicts with this tag and [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) seems to have been removed: [Replace the misleading [unity] tag with a more distinct tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269701/7711148)

But I think [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) was a poor choice to be the official tag for the game engine.

Current Unity synonyms:

[image]

Comment: I guess it's because `unity3d.com` was the official URL before it was renamed to `unity.com`. I still have `https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation/2d-mode` on my history...

Comment: unity3d.com is still a valid domain. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/index.html works, and unity3d.com redirects to unity.com. Even https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Unity3D&redirect=no exists (though it redirects to /wiki/Unity now)

Comment: I think this is my point exactly. `unity3d` is no longer the name of the product, every up-to-date reasource calls it `unity engine` or `unity`. Shouldn't we update the tag name accordingly?

Comment: The tag is now [tag:unity-game-engine]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> But I think [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) was a poor choice to be the official tag for the game engine.

As was mentioned in the comments, the website used to be Unity3D.com (and that TLD still works), so at the time the tag was chosen, it was arguably the correct choice.

That being said, Unity *is* now just called Unity, so I agree with the request that the 'parent' tag should be renamed to [unity-game-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-game-engine), and [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity), [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d), [unity2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity2d), etc. should be synonymized to it.